# ClickOnce Deployment Location Web

Tags: c#, deployment, clickonce, web-deployment

Is there a way to change the location where ClickOnce automatically installs a program from a web server? I need to have it place an Icon on the desktop automatically. 
Thanks!

Comment: Why is this a problem?  ClickOnce installs applications in the Application Cache.  It's easy to find the user's cache but the ClickOnce/MS Installer manages where these files are stored so you don't have to.

Comment: I am obviously missing something. The file paths that I am given when I search for the program are extremely long. Sorry for the dumb question, but how do you easily find the appCache?

Comment: I apologize for the vagueness of my statement. What I meant is you can get the location of the installation by checking the System.Application.ExecutablePath.  This location, however, will be different for each user.

Comment: Oh ok I see. I am just trying to make it so when a user installs the program from the web, a shortcut to the application appears on the desktop. I guess I would have to do that within the program though? It just seems fairly complex for a simple task.

Comment: I see.  Linked below is a just-the-code solution to your problem.  Note, I haven't tested it.  It looks pretty rock-solid, though.  http://geekswithblogs.net/murraybgordon/archive/2006/10/04/93203.aspx

Comment: Ok great. I really appreciate it!

Comment: Might want to consider editing your question to match the answer given. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are targeting .NET 3.5 or above, you can just check the box in the Options dialog in the publish tab to have a desktop shortcut created for you.